# How to change Evoluation notification sound?

Tags: 22.04, evolution

Is it possible to change the evolution "new mail" notification sound to a different one than the global system notification sound?

While there is a `Mail Notification` plugin for Evolution, this only redirects to the gnome sound settings, where I cannot set a custom sound for just one app.

Answer (score 0):

Sound files are in /usr/share/sounds/Yaru/stereo/
Change message-new-email.oga to whatever you want, just maintain file type.